# C#: Dragging/dropping between controls inside flow layout panel

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, flowlayoutpanel

I have a `Flow Layout Panel` control which contains several pictureboxes. To be concrete, FLP is an inventory and pictureboxes are items. When I drag PB outside of FLP and drop it on a control which is also outside of FLP, everything works fine.

But when I drag PB from FLP to drop it to another PB in FLP, problem arises. Dragging works fine, but dropping is not - PB isnt dropped on another picturebox but on the FLP. MouseDown, DragEnter and DragDrop events are set properly everywhere. Is there any way how to reach dropping on a control in a FLP?

Thanks.

Comment: It is probably because the drop actually registers on the FlowLayoutPanel and not the Control inside of it.

Comment: Can you show us the code portions the register the d&d events?